# Gradle JavaExec task failing with library class not found error in Android Studio

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, ormlite

I am trying to integrate the running of the ORMLite data 'compiler' utility in my android gradle script.  From various sources I have established how to place it in the build flow with the required dependencies to makes sure it runs after the java compile and a second task will update the apk with the generated database definitions file using aapt.

My main issue is that I can't get my OrmLiteConfigUtil extended class to run because the JavaExec task fails to locate  the OrmLiteConfigUtil class

```
Error:Gradle: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteConfigUtil
```

The task definition is as follows

```
applicationVariants.all { com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant variant ->

    def databaseTaskName = "${variant.name.capitalize()}DatabaseCompile"
    def buildDir = getBuildDir()
    def javaCompileTaskName = "compile" + variant.name.capitalize() + "Java"
    def javaTask = project.tasks.findByName("${javaCompileTaskName}")

    task "${databaseTaskName}" (type: JavaExec) {
        main = 'com.barclaycard.bespoke.android.data.local.DatabaseConfigUtil'

        dependencies {
            classpath files("${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/${variant.dirName}")
        }
    }

    if (javaTask != null) {
        println "Adding post-compile hook to ${variant.name}"
        javaTask.finalizedBy "${variant.name.capitalize()}DatabaseCompile"
    }

}
```

and is placed inside the android section of build.gradle

I have tried adding additional statements in the dependencies section of the task but to no avail.

```
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
```

(ClassNotFoundException thrown during task execution)

```
classpath 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
```

and

```
classpath files('com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48')
```

(Cannot convert URL 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48' to a file.)

I can't see how to get the JavaExec task to use the remote repo to find the required class.

```
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
```

is used in the main project dependencies and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be misunderstaning you a little bit here, but could it be that you are using the dependencies wrong? Might be this is suitable

```
dependencies {
    orm 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
}
...
task "${databaseTaskName}" (type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.barclaycard.bespoke.android.data.local.DatabaseConfigUtil'

    classpath configurations.orm + files("${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/${variant.dirName}")

...
}
```

A litt uncertain if that '+' is working. **configurations.orm** I think should make an impact.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - this approach worked.  As far as the '+' is concerned, I just used two `classpath` statements.  They are cumulative, each `classpath` statement appends to the class path.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it related to an environment variable set incorrectly:
export LOCAL_LIB=D:\LIB
vs
export LOCAL_LIB="D:\LIB"

so, the quotes were the problem.